# How to change properties of tooltip text?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am new to google charts, trying to make calendar chart.

I am using this :

```
 `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['calendar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
   var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

   dataTable.addColumn('date' , 'date'); 
   dataTable.addColumn('number', 'num');
   dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role:'tooltip'});

   dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2017, 11, 20), 150,'Hello'],
      [ new Date(2017, 11, 21), 130,'Hello']
      ]);

   var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('tooltip_action'));

   var options = { 
            title: "Calendar Chart", 
            colors: ['#e0440e'],
            height: 350
          };

   chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

`

It is working fine. But when I move cursor to 20/12/2017 and 21/12/2017 it is showing 'Hello' in very small text and small size.

And when I move cursor to other dates it is showing in bigger.

I want to change height and width of this text.

How to change properties of this tooltip text ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use html tooltips, then use a css class to style them

set the following option...

```
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
```

and column property --> `p: {html: true}`

`dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role:'tooltip', p: {html: true}});`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['calendar']
}).then(function () {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('date' , 'date'); 
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'num');
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role:'tooltip', p: {html: true}});
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ new Date(2017, 11, 20), 150,'<div class="tooltip">Hello</div>'],
    [ new Date(2017, 11, 21), 130,'<div class="tooltip">Hello</div>']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('tooltip_action'));

  var options = { 
    title: "Calendar Chart", 
    colors: ['#e0440e'],
    height: 350,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}

#tooltip_action {
  width: 1000px;
}

.tooltip {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip_action"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @WhiteHat !! It worked. Got an idea too - first enable 'html' and then use html div in tooltip texts with a classname and assign css properties. Thanks again :)